# How to fix mongodb Error: Network is unreachable

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, robo3t

I get this error, when I try to connect to MongoDB

```
Error:
Network is unreachable.
```

Running mongod before mongo shell didn't help .

When I restart my computer it works!!!Anyway I get that error again, something like 30 minutes later.

This is output from cmd, when I run command `mongod`

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod
2019-04-26T18:50:26.559+0400 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-04-26T18:50:26.562+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1092 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=DESKTOP-47AK9D5
2019-04-26T18:50:26.562+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2019-04-26T18:50:26.563+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.7
2019-04-26T18:50:26.563+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 1b82c812a9c0bbf6dc79d5400de9ea99e6ffa025
2019-04-26T18:50:26.564+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-04-26T18:50:26.565+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-04-26T18:50:26.565+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-04-26T18:50:26.565+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2019-04-26T18:50:26.566+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-04-26T18:50:26.566+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-04-26T18:50:26.567+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-04-26T18:50:26.568+0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2019-04-26T18:50:26.568+0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-04-26T18:50:26.568+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-04-26T18:50:26.568+0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

**Edit:** I found a problem. MongoDB Server turns off automatically. Just change service startup type to Manual.

[MongoDB Server Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt28o.png)